# Show that $b(\ ., \ .)$ it is not coercive.

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, sobolev-spaces

Let $b(\ .,\ .)$ a bilinear operator so that

$$b(u, \phi)= \int_0^T((u(t), \ \phi(t)))dt- \int_0^T(u(t), \ \phi'(t))dt,$$

where $((\ ., \ .))$ it is the inner product of $H_0^1(\Omega)$ (Sobolev Space) and $(\ .,\ .)$ of $L^2(\Omega)$.
Show that $b(\ .,\ .)$ is not coercive in $W$, where

$$W=\{\phi \in L^2(0,T;H_0^1(\Omega));\ \phi' \in L^2(0,T;L^2(\Omega)) \ \mbox{and} \ \phi(T)=0\}.$$

Comment: us any help is welcome ... I proved to $C>1$ considering $\phi$ so that $\phi(0)=0$.

Answer (score 1):

First note that you have
\begin{align*}b(u, u)
&= \int_0^T((u(t), \ u(t)))dt- \int_0^T(u(t), \ u'(t))dt \\
&= \int_0^T((u(t), \ u(t)))dt- \frac12 \, \int_0^T \frac{d}{dt}(u(t), \ u(t))dt \\
&= \int_0^T((u(t), \ u(t)))dt- \frac12 \, (u(T), \ u(T)) + \frac12 \, (u(0), \ u(0)) \\
&= \int_0^T((u(t), \ u(t)))dt+ \frac12 \, (u(0), \ u(0)).
\end{align*}
From here, you can find easy examples showing that $b$ is not coercive. Try $u(t,x) = u_1(t) \, u_2(x)$ with arbitrary $u_2$ and suitable $u_1$.

Comment: C depends on u? thanks

Comment: Who is $C{}{}{}{}$?

Comment: the constant of the definition of the coercivity ... which the form of the function $u_1$? I also made the development to this point

Comment: The last expression of $b(u,u)$ does not involve any derivatives in time. So you should try highly oscillating functions.